# Vim Regex: Add character before the last word of each line

Tags: regex, vim

```
Word1 Word2 Word3 ... Wordx LastWord
Word1 Word2 Word3 ... Wordx LastWord
```

How could I possibly add "|" before the last word of each line and return the following result using Regex in vim?

```
Word1 Word2 Word3 ... Wordx | LastWord
Word1 Word2 Word3 ... Wordx | LastWord
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I tried the following pattern which seemed to start selecting from the end, but I could not figure out how to make it stop at the first space in order to select the last word, given that its meaning is to neglect spaces. I really got confused on how this would work: /.[^ ]$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try following command

```
:%s/[^ ]*$/| &/
```

Or (as suggested by *IngoKarkat*)

```
:%s/\S*$/| &/
```

Comment: You can use `\S` (non-whitespace) instead of `[^ ]`.

Comment: I see, it selects all non white space, before the end! Thanx a lot!

Comment: @IngoKarkat thanks. added to ans. I'm habituated with `sed` and `grep` so tend to use `[^ ]` for compatibility

Answer (score 4):

Use this replace:

```
:%s/ \(\w\+\)$/ | \1/
```

Comment: That is strange since I tested it before posting.

Comment: Although I understand the logic, when I implement /\w$ in vim I receive " Pattern not found: \w$ ". The only pattern of this type that works is \w*$ which selects the \r character of the line.

Comment: You probably have older version of vim where `\w` isn't supported.

Comment: Is `:%s/ \([0-9a-zA-Z_]\+\)$/ | \1/` working for you?

Comment: Doh ... Actually `\w` is supported. The problem was that my lines were ending with the character `>` which was not mentioned in my question. Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 2):

To do this with your current `iskeyword` settings:

```
:%s/.*\<\zs/ | /
```

Comment: Thanx, it works perfectly, however I cannot understand how .*\< will match until the last word. .* -> select every character. \< -> Matches the begin of a word, why the last word and not the second word?

Comment: `.*` will take the longest match it can that keeps the pattern matchable, so e.g. `.*a` will match everything up to the last `a` on a line. The `\zs` in there sets the start-of-effect boundary.